# Iphone Game Develoment - Need design guidance

Tags: iphone, design-patterns

I have started programming a game for the iphone and as all beginners I feel like I am shooting in the dark. I just want to run my design and how my "graphics engine" works by you to see if it is anything close to standard design or good practise. Let me explain how it works:

For simplification reasons lets just say I have the following 3 classes:

**LevelView**: inherits from UIViewController and is a view with 10 buttons for each level of the game. Clicking a button creates a new GameViewController object (using initWithLevel) and instantiates it with an integer ( 1-10) according to the level the player chose.

**GameViewController**: inherits from UIViewController and has the initWithLevel(int) method and a big switch statement which performs the level setup according to the int that was passed. So it instantiates two types of objects (robots and planets) in various numbers according to each level. Each object it creates is inserted into an array belonging to a singleton. Then at the end it will start the gameloop which is another method in this class.

**GameView**: inherits from UIView and is where everything is drawn ( has a drawRect method) and where the touches Began,Moved and Ended methods are. What will happen for every gameLoop is that this will pull all objects from the global array (the array in the singleton) and according to what object it is it will draw the correct image at the correct location. ( location of robots and planets is stored within their respective objects as variables)

In the touches Began,Moved,Ended methods according to what the user does the relevant objects are pulled back from the Singleton array and their position/ability is updated. Therefore the next time the loop runs and they are drawn again the draw method wil update their location or behaviour.

Does this sound about right at this point? Should I be instantiating a GameViewController object to start the level? Should the gameLoop be in the GameViewController or should it be in the GameView. I have added the GameView onto the GameViewController in InterfaceBuilder It will draw the initial objects but I am not sure how to update them going forward. How do I call the drawRect method to update everything?

Anyways, sorry for the extremely long post. I am not looking for a specific answer just a review from someone more experienced in this to tell me:

1) yes you are going in the right direction design wise

2) no you need to rethink a few things

Thanks for your help

Stav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really really really recommend using a good game framework like Cocos2d, rather than rolling it all your own.

It's very fast and easy to get rolling with it, and a *lot* of top games were made with it.

It even has handling for "levels" like you are trying to do.

I downloaded it, and had my first test app up and running in 24 minutes!

Check it out at:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/

Comment: I checked it out. Looks powerful enough for what I am doing and pretty easy! I think I may switch my whole app to that! cheers

Comment: Hey - thanks for the comment. I am switching to cocos2d as it looks much easier and faster than the core framework I was using before. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I agree on the Cocos2d. On the other hand if you are interested in how the graphics work, start learning OpenGL ES, it's tough to learn but once you know it you aren't as limited as before by using frameworks that do all the work.

On your other question, the design. Apps are built on the MVC model. Depending on the scale of the app, you could put the game loop(logic) in the controller class or for a larger project (and a better design) you should separate the 2 in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment alJaree. One more question, is it good design to put my game objects in a singleton and transfer them between classes that way? is there any other way to do this? I checked out Cocos2d and it looks very easy to use an powerful enough for my needs. I may switch to that.

Comment: Sure. The singleton should do the trick. take a look at this post. The author uses cocos2d and discusses the singleton class. http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/

Comment: Thanks! I'm starting to convert all my menu structure to scene and implementing all the basics in cocos2d. After that the whole graphics engine part should be pretty easy! cheers!